# jQuery validation engine logical OR

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validation-engine

Using jquery validationEngine, I would like to validate a field as empty OR a valid date.

Does validationEngine support logical OR or would this require a custom method?

The following code would require a date.

```
<input type="text" id="someName" name="someName" 
    value="{$someValue}"  class="validate[required],custom[date]"/>
```

I need the correct logic inline for "empty/null OR custom[date]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class="validate[false,custom[date]]"
```

I don't know whether its a hack or valid to pass arg as `false`, I checked the API I didn't see any thing like that.

if the input tag contains value it will validate with date, otherwise it doesn't do anything.

http://jsfiddle.net/cx0rrea9/1/

Comment: Pavan, that would be the code for required and custom date and is in my example.  I need the code for empty/null OR custom[date].  Any thoughts on that?